# MYSQL returning no records from URL left string

Tags: mysql, string

```
SELECT
domain_usage.url,
LEFT(url,locate('?',url)) AS cleanURL
FROM
domain_usage
WHERE
MONTH(domain_usage.login_date) =  (Now()) AND
YEAR(domain_usage.login_date) =  (Now());
```

Returns no records, and no error ? 
im trying to clean the query string from URL field.....

Any thoughts ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your date comparisons are wrong. you're basically trying

```
3 = '2013-01-18 10:36:00'
```

you need to compare apples to apples:

```
MONTH(domain_usage.login_date) = MONTH(now())
```

Comment: Yeah I got that as soon as wrote it out and read it here, i tried to delete question, thanks

Answer (score 0):

modify your `WHERE` condtion,

```
SELECT domain_usage.url, LEFT(url,locate('?',url)) AS cleanURL 
FROM domain_usage
WHERE MONTH(domain_usage.login_date) = MONTH(CURDATE()) AND 
      YEAR(domain_usage.login_date) =  YEAR(CURDATE())
```